# What are all the events associated with a human mouse click?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser, dom-events

When a user clicks on a HTML element, it seems a number of JavaScript events *other than* just "click" are fired. For example, clicking on a input/text element also triggers events like *focus*, *mousedown*, *mouseup*, etc...

Essentially, when a **human** clicks on an element, what are all the events that get fired? (besides click!)

Comment: You should explain why you need it, it could be useful to others, right now it seems kind of random. With more details as to why you need it could make sure you are covering all the cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the specific button click, there will be:

```
mousedown
mouseup
click
```

If the mouse entered a new element in the period you are looking you may also see:

```
mousemove
mouseover
mouseenter

mouseleave (on other element)
mouseout   (on other element)
```

If the focus changes based on the click:

```
focusout   (on some other element)
blur       (on some other element)
focusin
focus
```

You can see an exact sequence of events in this jsFiddle that logs all the events: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/r9c7n5j2/

---

If the focus is elsewhere and you click into an input tag, you will see this sequence of events (for clarity, only one `mousemove` event is shown, but there will likely be many):

```
mouseover
mouseenter
mousemove
mousedown
focus
focusin
mouseup
click
```

Note: `focusin` is not yet supported in Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this bit in the [w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MouseEvent):

Should be what you're looking for. Also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) has a good overview of them

Comment: That's just a general list of Javascript events --- it does not list all the events *specifically* associated with a **human** mouse click.

Comment: It does not list all the events *specifically* associated with a **human** mouse click. Instead of me having to go through every Javascript event (or every Javascript "mouse" event), is there a resource that simply lists the *exact set* of events fired when a human clicks a mouse? E.g., this list must include the "focus" event, but must omit "blur event" in its listing

Comment: Probably, somewhere out there there is a blog post or something. If you look at 1.6.5 you'll see the other events, like focus, that are like mouse events.

Comment: Answers should contain the actual answer content within the answer, not just a link to a spec where the reader has to somehow piece together the answer themselves.

Comment: Also, the DOM 2 Events specification is pretty old. Much more recent are specifications like the [*WHATWG DOM Living Standard*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#events).